# CSS: align text with a spinkit (dynamical spinner in css)

Tags: css

I have a big mistake with css today.
I want to align and center a text and a dynamic css spiner that I found on http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/.
this kind of spinner are css one. The CSS code is like this:

```
.sk-circle {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative; }
  .sk-circle .sk-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; }
  .sk-circle .sk-child:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
            animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
            transform: rotate(30deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
            transform: rotate(60deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle4 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle5 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
            transform: rotate(120deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle6 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
            transform: rotate(150deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle7 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle8 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
            transform: rotate(210deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle9 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
            transform: rotate(240deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle10 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform: rotate(270deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle11 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
            transform: rotate(300deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle12 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
            transform: rotate(330deg); }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle2:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
            animation-delay: -1.1s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle3:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
            animation-delay: -1s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle4:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
            animation-delay: -0.9s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle5:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
            animation-delay: -0.8s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle6:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
            animation-delay: -0.7s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle7:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle8:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
            animation-delay: -0.5s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle9:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
            animation-delay: -0.4s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle10:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
            animation-delay: -0.3s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle11:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
            animation-delay: -0.2s; }
  .sk-circle .sk-circle12:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
            animation-delay: -0.1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }

@keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }
```

To put the spinner in the html you just have to use this code:

```
 <div class="sk-circle">
   <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
   <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
 </div>
```

Finally you have something like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hVIFGV6ebnooeLOJwdYH?p=preview

Now arrive my issue:

I want to had text on the right of the spinner.
A simple text like "your page is loading..."
I also want that my text and my spinner are center in the screen.

I try lot of solution but I don't find anyone that works well.

Someone can help me please,

Thank you all :)

Comment: this ? http://plnkr.co/edit/2FaDgF0uD3rW3UMA4CWM?p=preview inline-block + vertical-align + text-align

Comment: ok, shame on me, I just make this plunker to be easier to understand and it work really easy on it. I will check what is wrong on my website and why it don't work as on plunker. Thank you so much ^^